# How to properly communicate between service and form using XML

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, service

So Ive got a project installed that has a service and a form. The service loads XML files that the form creates. The problem is since the path to service and form AppDatas are different using

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

I had to install the service on User account rather than local system. I notice that most services are installed as local system. How would this affect the performance of the service, or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: The System does not have an environment so there is no path to the folder.  I think the normal process is to have project in admin account and then run as an admin.  Running as a User Account is equivalent, but then a the user will have access to modify (unless you are the user).  Performance is based on setting the priority of the service.  often a service run as a system service is set to run at normal priority so it doesn't effect the operating system performance. So any service the priority should be set according to its requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bordering on too broad. There are lots of ways you could approach your scenario. That said, since you already have an implementation, we can comment on it to address the *specific* parts of your question.

First, running as a regular user should be fine, assuming the service will operate correctly under that account. It's not ideal, but shouldn't really hurt anything. Typically, a service requires elevated privileges, which is both why it's a service in the first place and why it's run as the Local System or Local Service account. But if your service doesn't require those privileges, using a user account is fine.

That said, from your description it sounds like the GUI program is controlling the service by writing XML files to some special location which the service watches for and reads. This use of the file system as a form of inter-process communication (IPC) is itself not ideal and I would recommend a different approach.

Since you already have XML-based I/O, I would suggest using named pipes or some other network/socket-based IPC. You can wrap a stream object (e.g. `PipeStream` or `NetworkStream`) in a `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader` and then use the normal XML stuff you're already using to read and write accordingly.

Another alternative is WCF. There's a bit of a learning curve, and you have a bit less control over the precise serialization used to transmit your data, but the benefit is that, with Visual Studio's support, you spend less time implementing the XML/serialization side of things, and you can create new clients for the service simply by adding them in Visual Studio. The IDE will create the necessary data structures and configuration to connect to the service.

In either case, then you can run your service under the Local System account as would be typical of a service and the issue you're asking about just goes away. :)